# How do I write people doing something at the same time?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure, punctuation, commas

While Lorrainne got in the driver's seat mom got into the passenger seat.(they are switching places)

Answer (score 2):

There are many conjunctions for indicating simultaneous actions. You could fill in the blanks in the following sentences with *while*, *as*, *right as*, *at the same time that*, etc.

> **___** Lorrainne got in the driver's seat, Mom got in the passenger seat.
>
> Lorrainne got in the driver's seat **___** Mom got in the passenger seat.

You could use an adverb to specify that both actions occur at the same time.

> Lorrainne got in the driver's seat, and Mom **simultaneously** got in the passenger seat.

Or you could use a prepositional phrase to do the same.

> Lorrainne got in the driver's seat, and Mom got in the passenger seat **at the same time**.

All the above sentences make sense if Lorrainne and Mom are switching seats or if the two are just getting into the car. If they are specifically switching seats, then *switching seats* or *swapping seats* already implies simultaneous actions.

> Lorrainne moved from the passenger seat to the driver's seat, **swapping seats** with Mom.